# Get ping latency time value with Python

Tags: python, parsing, ping

I'm trying to write a simple script to ping an adress and retrieve the latency time. I've seen several solutions online but it doesn't work on my end.

```py
import subprocess
import re

p = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe","8.8.8.8"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
ping = p.communicate()[0]

timestr = re.compile("temps=[0-9]+ms").findall(str(ping))
```

`timestr` is just an empty list. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall(r'temps=[0-9]+\s*ms',str(ping))` solves my problem. I get the times with a combination of 0 to 9 of several numbers, `\s*ms` tells that it can have 0 to several spaces before `ms`.